# Android - API to check which device, wired headset or USB headset, is playing audio if both are connected

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, android-developer-api

I have a problem detecting which device, wired headset or USB headset is playing audio when both of them are connected to an Android device.

Is there an **API** which will allow checking that?

I have noticed that different devices behave in a different way. E.g. on Samsung S10+ with Android 9 the peripheral attached later is used to play audio. However on Moto G6 Android 7 and Samsung S8+ Android 9 wired headset is always used, no matter which peripheral was connected later.

I need this information to correctly configure the audio stream and to show which device is currently being used.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [MediaRouter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/mediarouter/media/MediaRouter) API.

MediaRouter.RouteInfo getSelectedRoute() is probably what you are looking for.

Also it allows you to register a listener to be notified when current audio device configuration changes(MediaRouter.Callback interface). Its onRouteSelected and onRouteUnselected callbacks are called when an
audio device starts/stops to play audio respectively.

Here's a log (abridged) from my MTK device demonstrating attributes of MediaRouter.RouteInfo and flow of events that occurred when I plugged in wired headphones while listening to music via Jabra Bluetooth headset.

> onRouteChanged RouteInfo{ name=Headphones, description=null,
>   status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=System
>   types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false },
>   supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO ,
>   presentationDisplay=null }
>
> onRouteUnselected RouteInfo{ name=Jabra MINI v1.0.5,
>   description=Bluetooth audio, status=null, category=RouteCategory{
>   name=System types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO 
>   groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ,
>   presentationDisplay=null }
>
> onRouteSelected RouteInfo{ name=Headphones, description=null,
>   status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=System
>   types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false },
>   supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO ,
>   presentationDisplay=null }
>
> onRouteRemoved RouteInfo{ name=Jabra MINI v1.0.5,
>   description=Bluetooth audio, status=null, category=RouteCategory{
>   name=System types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO 
>   groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ,
>   presentationDisplay=null }

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I will check it but probably it will work only when using stream type Media for e.g. playing music. I am using VoiceCommunication or VoiceRecognition and this API will probably won't work.